# MVVM and RecyclerView and LiveData

Tags: android, mvvm, android-recyclerview, android-room, android-livedata

I'm trying to implement a RecyclerView in a fragment using a [MVVM approach](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html) but I'm facing issues for the **refresh of its content during the first load**, bellow are the steps I'm following :

1. I create the RecyclerView
2. Set a custom adapter on it

   ```
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
   ```
3. Subscribe to notifications on my model (persistance layer done with [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html))

   ```
    viewModel.getVideosForCategoryId(category.getId()).observe(this,
    videos -> {
        if (videos.size() > 0) {
            long catId = videos.get(0).getIdCategory();
           if (videosListAdapters.containsKey(catId)) {
               videosListAdapters.get(catId).updateList(videos);
           }
        }
   });
   ```
4. Update the RecyclerView via AsyncListDiffer as shown [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/AsyncListDiffer.html)

   ```
   public void updateList(List<Video> newList) {
       differ.submitList(newList);
   }
   ```

However, when the Observer is called for the first time, **the data is there** `videos.size() > 0` and passed to the RecyclerView via `updateList(videos)` but the recycler view doesn't refresh itself and the callbacks from `AsyncListDiffer` are not called :

```
        @Override
        public boolean areItemsTheSame(
            @NonNull Video oldUser, @NonNull Video newUser) {
            // User properties may have changed if reloaded from the DB, but ID is fixed
            return oldUser.getIdVideo() == newUser.getIdVideo();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areContentsTheSame(
            @NonNull Video oldUser, @NonNull Video newUser) {
            // NOTE: if you use equals, your object must properly override Object#equals()
            // Incorrectly returning false here will result in too many animations.
            return oldUser.equals(newUser);
        }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: are you trying to update the recyclerview via diffutil ?

Comment: I'm using the submitList(List<T>) from the diffutil to update it yes.

Comment: the only case i can think of when it might occur that none of callback methods are getting called is when both of the list (i.e old and new ) contains same referenced objects . You can try to look at the reference of objects in both the lists.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I'm not managing the old and new lists as I'm using AsyncListDiffer as described in the link above.

Comment: I worked around my problem by using DiffUtil.Callback instead of AsyncListDiffer.